# Connecting code to UI in storyboard with multiple ViewControllers, Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode-storyboard

I have a storyboard project in Xcode. I have added an additional ViewController and dropped in a button, text box, etc. I can get from the initial to the secondary View Controller, but I cannot seem to be able to connect the button to the code. I've tried adding additional classes with XIBs and even from a blank adding in the XIBs. How do I connect the code I have written for a button to do work on the second View Controller?

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: I know the code works, I've used it in other apps. I have created the button in the header file and also stated the IBAction statement in both the header and implementation files. I cannot connect the objects on the second and subsequent View Controllers to the code. The blue line appears, but makes no connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the button created on the storyboard. You have to make an

```
-(IBAction)clickButton...
```

in the .h and .m code files. You can easily connect the code to the button by dragging the line from the dot (in front of the code name) to the button.

If you have created the Button fully in code. You have to specify which code to be executed on click.

```
[self.buttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I have the code in the header and implementation files. The issue comes down to that on the second UIVIewController and subsequent VCs, I cannot connect the code to the object on the UI with the code. Even with the creation of new .h & .m, I cannot make the connection. I will be burning my brain today on different methods and if I make it work, I will post how.

Comment: Still a no go. I find all sorts of information regarding navigation control, but I don't want that. I want it to work just like before they upgraded to 5. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Aah, now I understand your problem. Go to Storyboard. Open the Utilities window (on the right). Klik on your view in the drawing area. In the list on the left you will see that one item from the view is selected. For this the top level of the view has to be selected. Now, in the Utilities window on the right click on the 3rd tab (the Identity Inspector). In the list is a area called "Custom Class". Here you have to specify the name of your file. So e.g. InfoViewController when your .m and .h are called InfoViewController.m and InfoViewController.h. Now you can connect them using the manual!

Comment: That's it Vincent. That solved my problems. Now to figure out the next portion....populating a view with UIImages that have 3 buttons with them programmatically....this will be the hardest part I think and so far, I'm not making headway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer. You add new files to your project, and just for giggles, we'll call them NewViewController of the UIViewController class. Then, highlight the second view controller in the storyboard, choose identity inspector, and under Custom Class (at the top) you change the class to the name of the recently added NewViewController class. Now, all your code will connect to objects and so on. Thanks again for the help all and now I can rest in peace lol.